# How do I scan and capture Linux folder name using SAS Programming?

Tags: sas

I want to list out all the folder names in a directory. For example, sas/data/ has 10 folders, not CSV or TXT, just folder and I want to list out all folder name into the code or dataset. Is there a way to do so?

Currently I have a script that is able to print out all the file name but not folder name. The script is as below:

```
 %macro list_files(dir,ext);   %local filrf rc did memcnt name i;  
 %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,&dir));   %let
 did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf));      

    %if &did eq 0 %then %do; 
     %put Directory &dir cannot be open or does not exist;
     %return;   %end;

    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(dnum(&did));   

    %let name=%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i));

 /*      %if %qupcase(%qscan(&name,-1,.)) = %upcase(&ext) %then %do;*/
       %if %qscan(&name,2,.) ne %then %do;
         %put &dir\&name;

         data _tmp;
           length dir $512 name $100;
           dir=symget("dir");
           name=symget("name");
         run;
         proc append base=want data=_tmp;
         run;quit;

       %end;
       %else %if %qscan(&name,2,.) = %then %do;        
         %list_files(&dir\&name,&ext)
       %end;

    %end;    %let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did));    %let
 rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf));     

 %mend list_files; %list_files(/sasdata/data/,*)
```

How can i tweak it to print out all folder name ?

Comment: What output do you want?  Why not just remove the test of the EXTension?  Perhaps something like in this post?  https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/listing-all-files-within-a-directory-and-subdirectories/m-p/332616/highlight/true#M74887

Comment: Folders don't have extensions. You can use that logic to find all folders though I think the code may need some small changes to account for that. Do you understand the code enough to modify it to account for that?

Comment: Folders could have extensions.  A folder is a path that fails to open with FOPEN but does open with DOPEN. Sure is an ugly reality for the DOPEN approach.  Far better, if policy allows, is to pipe the stdout of an OS *find* command.